# Can the data usage be Oriented by Consume of Demand?

Tags: router, ieee-802.11, internet, private-vlan, access-control

Let's imagine that a LAN house, solve to charge financially your users, through of **data usage** consumption and not by **time** of use.

It Is possible do control individually of assignment of data usage for users connected to a private network? is possible to assign this consume of controlled way and with safety?

> Example One: The user paid to use 1GB of data and passed using for four hours doing search at the google.
>
> Example Two: Some other user paid for the same 1GB but passed using for one hour playing some game MMORP (that consume very many data)

---

After consume this data, the connection is finished, equal when the time ends out in LAN houses

Exist technology for to do this type of control?

Someone already saw some enterprise working in this way?

Comment: I don't follow. The bandwidth is how many bits per second on a link. The link will have a specific bandwidth, You can use QoS to limit a user to a percentage or absolute value of the full link bandwidth.

Comment: What happens when they use up 1GB?  Do you stop them, or do you charge them more money?

Comment: I think you are confusing bandwidth with data usage. The bandwidth is the rate measured in bits per second, but data usage measured in bytes is how much data you have put through the link.

Comment: Yes, it true, thanks for improve and explain the ask

Comment: I find it very hard to understand this question.

Comment: You can highlight the hard points? for me to try to explain?

Comment: someone can help me the improve the question? it is much broad? or it is out scope? problems with the write english?

Comment: I think we understand the question, but perhaps you don't understand the answers. As Ron Trunk points out, you can use NetFlow, or IPFIX as it it now called, to deal with this. You will require enterprise-grade equipment to do this.

Comment: I understand the answers, but do not understand the down votes =(

Comment: Not a lot of detail here and I am a bit confused about what you are trying to accomplish, but seems like RADIUS could provide everything needed.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: No, yet no was answered, unfortunately =(

Answer (score 2):

If you want to measure traffic and charge users based on how much traffic they generate, you will need to configure Netflow (or similar) to record traffic use.

If you want to limit each users' share of bandwidth, you can configure your router to limit each user's share of the available bandwidth.

Both require commercial-grade devices.  You should consider whether the cost and effort to set this up is worth the benefit.

Comment: Thanks for to answer, which is commercial devices you be talking? you can give an example? I imagined that a router combined with sotfware and one professional network engineer would help with the situation.

Comment: Sadly, product recommendations are off-topic.  You can Google for "Netflow collector" and find commercial and open-source products.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the problem is how to charge users based on *how fast* they consume data, rather than (or in addition to) *how much* data they consumed

Cisco IOS has a "show interfaces" command, where you can see this:

```
GigabitEthernet2/11 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 
  ...
  ...
  5 minute input rate 24871000 bits/sec, 2649 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 331000 bits/sec, 107 packets/sec
     686062059 packets input, 383091840479 bytes, 0 no buffer
     ...
     ...
```

So, if your users are all on different physical interfaces, you can use the above information. Obviously you need to have external software that continuously polls for this and stores it somewhere, because the 5 minute rate displayed by IOS is only for the last 5 minutes in time; there is no historical record.

But is this really for an enterprise deployment? If not, this question is off-topic on this site :-).

Comment: yes, would be for a enterprise solution =)